# I need a clean way to identify record types based on contents

Tags: c#

I have strings of eight characters like below. The presence of zeros in the last column identifies these as type pr, pa, fo or it records:

```
01020304
01020300
01020000
01000000
```

I already coded the following but it looks clumsy to me.

```
        if ( id.Substring(2) == "000000") {
            // pr record
        } else if ( id.Substring(4) == "0000") {
            // pa record
        } else if ( id.Substring(6) == "00") {
            // fo record
        } else {
            // it record
        }
```

Can anyone think of a cleaner way to code this?

Comment: It's possible with a bit more information about the overall usage here that some alternative solutions might be available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By `value.TrimEnd('0').Length`   ?

Comment: I am trying this now. I think if I can use this in conjunction with a case statement it might be the most clean looking solution although I also like the other idea of constants.

Answer (score 3):

Not massively different to what you've got, just a bit more readable IMO.

```
        const string PR = "000000";
        const string PA = "0000";
        const string FO = "00";

        if (id.EndsWith(PR))
        {
            // pr record
        }
        else if(id.EndsWith(PA))
        {
            // pa record
        }
        else if (id.EndsWith(FO))
        {
            // fo record
        }
        else
        {
            // it record
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Nothing wrong with testing the strings, however:

1. substring probably produces a new string object
2. is there no `endswith` in C#?
3. it is fairly easy to write function that counts the number of trailing zeros. Then you could do a `switch(trailingZeros(id)) { case 0: ... }`

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a look at the [Filehelpers](http://www.filehelpers.com/) library -- it's got all sorts of infrastructure to read and process records, including a way to determine different record types -- see "[Multirecords](http://www.filehelpers.com/example_multirecords.html)".

Note: the main Filehelpers website is based on the 2.0 release of this library.  A newer version exists in a [public repository](http://teamcity.codebetter.com/viewLog.html?buildId=lastSuccessful&buildTypeId=bt66&tab=artifacts&guest=1).  In either case, I'd recommend grabbing the source code for the library, as I haven't seen a ton of activity in terms of new development for this library.